# close Dialogbox when click ESCAPE(ESC) in GWT

Tags: gwt, keylistener, dialog

How can I add something like addCloseHandler to dialogbox that to close when click the ESC key?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can override the `onPreviewNativeEvent()` method of the `DialogBox` class:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    ExtendedDialogBox dialog = new ExtendedDialogBox();

    dialog.add(new Label("some content"));

    dialog.show();
}

private class ExtendedDialogBox extends DialogBox {

    @Override
    protected void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        super.onPreviewNativeEvent(event);
        switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
            case Event.ONKEYDOWN:
                if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ESCAPE) {
                    hide();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the only issue is that this is preview event so it could be handled by some dialog child. for instance selects (ListBox) are closed with esc etc. for such cases i use dup of CellBasedWidgetImpl#isFocusable to check on event.getNativeEvent().getTarget().cast().

Comment: thanks a lot, search in google , top in result and this worked for me as i wish

Comment: Whereas I'd prefer `if (event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONKEYDOWN)` instead of the switch/break, but both will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDownPreview(char key, int modifiers) {
     switch (key) {
       case KeyCodes.KEY_ESCAPE:
         hide();
         break;
     }

     return true;
 }
```

Comment: unfortunately is deprecated method, I can't use it