# Catch GWT ClickEvent at Button

Tags: java, gwt, button, dialog, onclick

I have a button which shows a DialogBox when you click on it.

However if you click on the button it shows the DialogBox and th same time it will close and then open again.

It seems that the closeEvent of the DialogBox is thwrown before the clickEvent on the button. So if you check dialogBox.isShowing() it will open again. Because the dialog is closed when the clickEvent to show the box is thrown.

My idea was to catch the onClick event and throw it away but I don't know how to do this.

Anybody knows a way to fix this Problem?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you share what you have tried with code snippets? Did you try autohide or modal feature of DialogBox? Can you explain your requirement in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a variable to hold the status of the dialog.

```
if(myDialogOpen==false)
{
    openDialog();
}
```

Or you could hold dialogbox as variable in the class you're using.

```
DialogBox myDialog;
if(myDialog==null)
{
    openDialog()
}
```

Either way you would have to reset the variable when you open or close the dialogbox. Essentially if the dialogbox is already open it does nothing.

These are a few possible ideas,maybe if you add some of the code of what you have done so far I can give you a better answer.

Comment: The problem is when I have a variable to hold the state of the box, the box is closed. So the variable will be set to boxIsClosed and then the onclickEvent get fired. So for the clickEvent the box is closed and will be shown again

Answer (score 1):

Asking about 
[event.preventDefault()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent.html#preventDefault%28%29) ??

you can catch the event inside the [click handler of button](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiHandlers).

Comment: The event.preventDefault() is something I was looking for. But I am to stupid to get both to work. Either you can click on the button to close the box. But then you have to click it serval times if you close the box by clicking outside of it. Or you can click outside the box to close ist but then the button won't work.

Comment: Create a final object of dialog and show and hide by maintaining a global variable  on clicks.

Comment: And update the global variable on click of the doument like here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301859/close-dialogbox-when-click-escapeesc-in-gwt