# closing a dialog box with esc button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dialog box #acronymPickerDialog that gets destroy on click of the #cancelBtn. however now I notice that when I click the escape button although the box appears to close, it still remains pasted at the bottom of the page. In other words, it's not getting destroy `onClick` of the Esc button. I need code that destroys this dialog box when I click on the Esc key.

It's set up like this right now:

```
events: {
    "click #okBtn": "selectAcronym",
    "click #cancelBtn": "closeAcronymPicker"
},


closeAcronymPicker: function () {  
    this.destroy();
}
```

Comment: Find a script on Stackoverflow that may help you out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301859/close-dialogbox-when-click-escapeesc-in-gwt[link]

Answer (score 1):

Try `remove()` instead of `destroy()`. Something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  if ( event.keyCode == 27 )   {
     document.getElementById('your-dialog-box').remove()
  }
})
```

Comment: `keyCode` is now deprecated use `e.key === "Escape"` instead.
cf [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3369624/13448212)